# Why does the UK compete in sports sometimes as "GBR" and sometimes as each of its individual nations?

Tags: united-kingdom, sports

In football and some other sports England, Wales, NI and Scotland compete as one independent country but at olympics, saling, skiing etc compete as "GBR"
What is reason for that?

UK has just one nationality(British) then it doesn't make sense that countries compete separetly..

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if this is politics but rather the rules of the sport/event.

Comment: @JoeW I dont think sport can force someone to compete as union of states or as one state...

Comment: Why exactly can't a sport/event decide the rules for how countries compete? The people running the event are the ones who decide the rules.

Comment: I don't have the time to elaborate right now, but it's definitely more of a sporting reason than a political one. England, Scotland etc. were often among the first and most influential national teams to be founded in a given sport, so their existence predates the notion that sub-divisions shouldn't have their own teams. In football, the precedent has actually led to other non-sovereign territories like Gibraltar and the Faroe Islands getting national teams; on the flipside, in cricket, the Caribbean nations are collectively represented by a single "West Indies" team.

Comment: @JoeW For example USA or in past Yugoslavia compete as one country in football.  UK has just one nationality(British) then it doesnt make sense that  countries compete separtely..

Comment: Possible dupe: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/65885/28994

Comment: Seems like an exact duplicate to me. Same subject, same examples, se answer.

Comment: @user628075 Go to a pub in Scotland and shout to the assembled people there that UK has just one nationality (British). Good luck coming out with your face intact.

Comment: As F1Krazy mentioned there are historical reasons around the sports as to why they compete differently for some sports.

Comment: The UK has at least four native nationalities,  some count six or more.

Comment: @DavidHammen hahhahahahha So who in UK  consider himself British? nobody?

Comment: @user628075 As a Brit, I can tell you it depends. Some consider themselves British, some consider themselves English/Scottish/Welsh/Irish (especially outside of England), some (myself included) consider themselves both. Just as someone living in, say, Texas may consider themselves to be American, Texan, or both.

Comment: [Lots of entities that aren't independent nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_men%27s_national_association_football_teams) have men's football teams: Wikipedia lists more than 20 (see note 3).

Comment: @F1Krazy0 **"(especially outside of England)"**  So UK was/is England idea?

Comment: @user628075 No, the UK was a union that all parties agreed to. At the time, however, it was ruled over by a monarch with considerably more power. Under the modern parliamentary system, however, England wields far more influence over the UK than the other three: the UK's Parliament is based in England, and the majority of its MPs represent English constituencies. It's analogous to Brexit: the primary driving factor was that the UK disliked how much power the EU had over them, just as many in Scotland now dislike how much power the UK has over them.